# Terminated due to timeout in Hackerrank (using malloc in cpp)

Tags: c++, performance, memory-efficient

so I am pretty new programmer and I have just started doing questions on Hackerrank. I tried a question and it compiles and work on offline ide. But shows error on hackerrank. A prompt answer would really help me.

[image]

This is the Virtual representation of the Spiral of prime numbers(For understanding purposes)

**Now the problem**
 The prime numbers are written in a spiral form starting from the origin (0, 0) and moving as shown in the diagram above. The numbers shown in the right column and the bottom row are the column numbers and row numbers respectively ( i.e. y and x coordinates)

The objective is to find the position (x and y coordinates) of a given prime number.

**ERROR**
When I run the code in hackerrank 2 out of 3 test cases work. But for one test case it shows Error terminated due to timeout.
The code I wrote is the following :

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int prime(int a)
{
    int count, h=0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= 12000000; i++)
    {
        count = 0;
        for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            h = h + 1;
        }
        if (a == i)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return h;

}
void spiral(int h)
{
    int stepnum=1, totalsteps = 2;
    int x_coordinate = 0, y_coordinate = 0;
    int operatn = 1;
    for(int i=2;i<=h;i++)
    {
        if (stepnum <= (totalsteps/2))
        {
            x_coordinate = x_coordinate + operatn;
        }
        else
        {
            if (stepnum <= totalsteps)
            {
                y_coordinate = y_coordinate + operatn;
            }
        }
        if (stepnum == totalsteps)
        {
            stepnum = 0;

            operatn = -1 * operatn;

            totalsteps = totalsteps + 2;


        }
        stepnum++;

        }

    cout << "x coordinate = "<<x_coordinate<< " y coordinate = "<<y_coordinate<<endl;

}

int main()
{
    int t;
    int* p;
    cout<<"Enter the number of cases :"<< endl;
    cin >> t;
    int test;
    p=(int*)malloc(t*4);
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        cin >> *(p+i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        test = prime(*(p + i));
        spiral(test);

    }
}
```

Comment: `p=(int*)malloc(t*4);` use `sizeof(int)` because there's no guarantee int is always 4 bytes. Really though, use `new` or a `vector`. Test and profile your code using the limits of the test cases as a guide. Look for the worst case scenario and make sure you are under the time limit for that. For a problem like this you generally want to find a way to cache as much data as you can so you don't calculate it every time.

Comment: The primality test can be sped up. No need to save the test cases in an array (I also used to when I was a beginner); take the input, do your computation and output it on a new line. The tester will check if whole of your output file matches theirs. I see the function `prime` is calculating the "rank" of the prime `a`, it can also be sped up by calculating the ranks of all the primes (until the maximum which must be given in the problem statement) before taking any input and then finding the rank will take just one lookup of the precomputed array. Similar can be done for the function `spiral`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this loop:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 12000000; i++)
...
    for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++)
    ...
```

You will end up doing on the order of n^2 iterations of your inner loop, where n=12000000, so that's 144*10^12 iterations of your inner loop.

Let's assume every iteration takes 1 nanosecond (it will actually be a lot longer), so that's 144*10^12 / 10^9 = 144000 seconds, or ~1.7 days, for a call to `prime` to complete, unless you break on `if (a == i)`.

So if your test case happens to call `prime` with a large `a`, exceeding the allotted time budget is likely.